# How to get final status with filtering each date in Power Bi dax query

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have few jobs which runs on its scheduled time each day. I have logTime, Job_Name, Status. I have to get the final status as if on a particular day job is success, failed or InProgress.

Considering below, I have to get the final_status Column.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a lookup table, which assigns a numeric value to each status - in ascending order:

```
+-----------+------------+
| status ID |   status   |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | Succeeded  |
|         2 | Inprogress |
|         3 | Failed     |
+-----------+------------+
```

Create a relationship between 'status' in your job table and this status table.

Now you can add a calculated column to your job table, to calculate the max status for each day:

```
FinalStatus = 
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        StatusTable[status],
        StatusTable[status ID],
        MAXX ( 
            FILTER ( 
                JobTable,
                JobTable[logTime] = EARLIER ( JobTable[logTime] )
            ),
            RELATED ( StatusTable[status ID] )
        )
    )
```

See https://excel.solutions/so20181206_lookupstatus/ for a worked example